# How to create a series of class instances in a for loop, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, addchild

In my library I have a bunch of classes named tip1, tip2, tip3, tip4...and so on. Is it possible to create one instance of each on the stage using a for loop? I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

```
var tips:int = 12;
for(var i:int = 1; i<=tips; i++){
    var tipName:String = "tip"+i

    var tip:MovieClip = new tipName();
    tip.name = "tip" + i
    tip.x = stage.width;
    tip.y = 0;
    addChild(tip);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the "getDefinitionByName" part.

```
// Up top
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

// Down below
var tips:int = 12;
for (var i:int = 1; i < tips; ++i ) {
  var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName('tip' + i) as Class;
  var tip:Object = new myClass();
  tip.name = "tip" + i; 

....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var tip:MovieClip = new tipName();
```

Try (written from memory)

```
var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName(tipName) as Class;
var tip:MovieClip = new clazz();
```

Also, you generally want to use `stage.stageWidth` instead of `stage.width`, since the latter will return the stage bounding box width (which might not be the same as the area the swf file covers).